# Add multiple fields to attribute table by python, with a prompt window for parameters

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, shapefile, python-toolbox

I know how to add field to arcmap shapefile using Python:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "H:\pythonexercise\NZL_rds\NZL_roads.shp"
arcpy.AddField_management("NZL_roads", "LENGTH", "TEXT","","","50")
```

But how to make the python code prompt a window for "field", "data type" and "length"? Also, what if I want add many fields at once like below:

- field "SPEEDLIMIT" data type as "num" and length "3".
- field "BREADTH" datatype as "num" and length "4"
- field "LANE" datatype as "num" and length "4"

It should be dynamic, not fixed like my code.

Answer (score 0):

Input can be asked this way:

```
var = raw_input("Enter something: ")
print "you entered ", var
```

For multiple input, you can ask:

```
var1, var2 = raw_input("Enter two field names separated by commas :").split(',')
```

Comment: Pure Python can do that but how does this "solution" work with the Python Toolbox that the asker appears to be writing?  I think you and the asker should expand your posts to show a code snippet that works up to where the asker is stuck or where you claim to have the solution.